# How do equivalent of UIImage.withTintColor, in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin.ios, uiimage

In Apple docs for iOS 13.0+, [UIImage class has method withTintColor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/3327300-withtintcolor).

However, the Xamarin.iOS equivalent [UIImage class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uiimage?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12) lacks this method.

Is there a way to do this?

(I don't think the alternative technique of setting `UIImageView.TintColor` helps me, because I need to programmatically draw the tinted image into another bitmap.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin renames `withTintColor` method to `ApplyTintColor`:

```
var tintedImage = srcImage.ApplyTintColor(myUIColor);
```